# Can't set delay in libgdx

Tags: java, libgdx

I want to remove an index from an array after some time, I want it to fall, then delete it.

```
private final int gravity = 4;
private long lifeTime=0;
private long delay = 20000L; 

public void objGravity() {
 while (array.get(array.size - 1).y > 0)
  array.get(array.size - 1).y -= gravity;

 lifeTime = System.currentTimeMillis();
 lifeTime += Gdx.graphics.getDeltaTime();

 if (lifeTime > delay) {
  array.removeIndex(array.size - 1);
  lifeTime = 0;
 }
}
```

The object gets removed from array immediately as if there's no delay whatsoever, so it doesn't appear to be falling down on the screen.

**Update**

I removed time and so on. I added a counter to count how many objects need to be removed and then I do a loop that removes array.size-1 as long as counter>0.

Not sure if it's the best approach, seems like a hack but I don't want to do threads on old mobile phones. If you have a better idea please share

Comment: Have you read what System.currentTimeMillis() returns? .. its going to be some large value, like 1349333576093. Then, adding the Gdx.graphics.getDeltaTime() (also, preferably you use the float delta value in your game/screen's render() method btw) - this will return the value since last render tick (in milliseconds), which is usually like 16 (depending on garbage collection or GPU handlings, from my experience). So basically your logic says, if 1349333576093+16 is greater than 20000L, enter that if statement - doesn't seem ideal. For my projects I use Guava's Stopwatch class to implement delay

Comment: @mcw damn! haven't thought much about it, it was the accepted answer on stackoverflow with 7 upvotes i jut took it, what's a better way to do it?

Comment: What's a better way to do what?

Comment: @Lynob you can't use `while` here.

Comment: @AbhishekAryan I removed all that code and updated the question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't fire threads inside the render method, it's not safe, can cause thread leaks, a lot of other problems and will be harder to maintain your code, to handle time use a variable adding delta time every time render is called, when this variable is superior a 1.0f means that one second has passed, your code would be something like this:

```
        private float timeSeconds = 0f;
        private float period = 1f;

        public void render() {
            //Execute handleEvent each 1 second
            timeSeconds +=Gdx.graphics.getRawDeltaTime();
            if(timeSeconds > period){
                timeSeconds-=period;
                handleEvent();
            }

            [...]

        }

        public void handleEvent() {
             [...]
        }
```

To keep organized i personally have an array on my main game class that holds all my timed events and process everything on the render cycle.